# How do I use the k() function to receive data in kdb/q

Tags: java, c#, asynchronous, kdb

Using the c.cs interface found in [Interfacing with C#](http://code.kx.com/q/interfaces/csharp-client-for-q/), how do I use the `k()` function to receive data from a long-running computation?

What I would like to do is

```
conn.ks("compute_long_running_function[]");
```

Do something else

```
results=conn.k();//wait for data
```

However, this latter call does not return the last result -- it times out indefinitely unless `/T {N}` has been set beforehand.

Is there a way to send data from the server to the client that is waiting for it?  How else would one use the `k()` function with no arguments.

Note that this question also applies to the java interface, which is nearly identical.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The k() function will block until it receives data from the remote socket. So if your function looked like this:

```
compute_long_running_function:{[] r:til 1000; neg[.z.w] r }
```

the function result will be sent over the loopback connection and be retrieved by conn.k()

The alternative is you just do:

```
results=conn.k("compute_long_running_function[]");
```

which will return the results of the function when they are ready. But you might have known that already.

Regards,

David

Answer (score 1):

If you call `ks` the return value of your function is ignored and you cannot use `k()` to retrieve it.

You only use k() to receive data that is *explicitly* sent to you by the `q` process the way @David shows by using negative of the client handle.